# Conditional WHERE statement in SQL uses Index Scan instead of Index Seek

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, conditional-statements

Consider the following code:

```
DECLARE @TaskId int;
SET @TaskId = 594725;

SELECT Report.Amount FROM Report WHERE Report.TaskId = @TaskId;

SELECT Report.Amount FROM Report WHERE (@TaskId = -1 OR Report.TaskId = @TaskId);
```

I have a nonclustered index on the table Report with the column **TaskId** indexed.
The first **SELECT** uses the index with an **INDEX SEEK** but the second one falls back to an **INDEX SCAN** due to the conditional check of the @TaskId variable. Is there any way to have the conditional check (if e.g. the **@TaskId** is a filter and **-1** should return all rows) and still get the query to use an **INDEX SEEK**?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
IF (@TaskId = -1)
    SELECT Report.Amount FROM Report
ELSE
    SELECT Report.Amount FROM Report WHERE Report.TaskId = @TaskId
```

When @TaskId = -1, of course it won't do an index seek as it will just be reading all the data.

**Update:**
Check out [this excellent article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) on this - dynamic search is a common scenario.
Something you should be aware of is execution plan caching as you could be experiencing bad performance when you switch from one set of "optional" parameters to another - hence you may end up using a poor execution plan, giving bad performance. In this case, you would want to consider using OPTION(RECOMPILE) hint so that it generates a plan fresh each time, which would be the best plan for that specific set of parameters. Check out the article in full though.

Comment: Thanks, yes that works. But if I have e.g. 10 variables that all needs conditional checks (e.g. a report with filters as a stored procedure) then the code gets out of control.

Comment: @brunnsbe - see the link in my edit. It's well worth a full read.

Comment: Yes, interesting article! But rewriting procedures to use dynamic sql is quite a work. :-(
The better solution (where SQL Server seems to understand the conditional part) doesn't work in SQL2005 due to the OPTION (RECOMPILE) hint not being implemented properly.